# Navigating dialog with VoiceOver scrolls underlying web page?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

I've implemented a popup dialog that disables scrolling the webpage behind it by setting `overflow:hidden` on the `body`. It works well and because I've set `role="dialog"` and I focus an appropriate element, it allows users with screen readers to navigate the dialog without being able to navigate to the underlying webpage content. This dialog contains a `table`. However, I noticed an odd issue. When hitting control option and any arrow key while any table element is focused (not any other element in the dialog), the underlying webpage is scrolled down a bit as if I had hit the down arrow while the dialog was not presented.

How can I ensure the underlying webpage is not scrollable when hitting the VoiceOver controls to move between elements? Do you believe this could be a VoiceOver bug?

Comment: How about an example or a video of what you're describing? Have you tested this in other browsers/screen readers? This doesn't sound like a significant issue.

Comment: @patrickfox Chrome and FF don't even support VoiceOver hardly at all, can't get it to focus on anything on the webpage. May not be a big deal, just a bit annoying to the sighted user.